# Using Active Record to Find a Join Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have several models associated with a `:has_many => :through` relationship:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_members
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_members
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_members
  has_many :users, :through => :group_members
end

class GroupMembers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

It's easy to find the relationships between groups and users with ActiveRecord:

```
groups = @user.groups
users = @group.users
```

But what if I wanted to find the join table that a group and a user share? Right now the best solution I can come up with is to use a class method. For instance, in the User model I have:

```
def group_member_for(group)
    self.group_members.where(:group_id => group.id).first
end
```

This works fine, but I suspect there's a cleaner approach. Perhaps even an approach that directly uses ActiveRecord associations. Something like:

```
group_member = @user.groups.group_member
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do the following:

```
user.group_members
# and
group.group_members
# or
GroupMember.where(user_id: user.id, group_id: group.id)
```

Comment: How is it that the first two do what the OP asked? It seems very different to me?

Comment: It seems silly that Rails doesn't have a convenience method like `user.group_members(group)` to grab the related record.

Comment: @MichaelFok You can just run `user.groups.find(group.id)`